# Como ler arquivo que está dentro do .apk?

Tags: android

Estou com um pequeno problema no desenvolvimento de um app.
Preciso ler as informações de um arquivo que fica dentro do .apk do meu app, ou seja. Esse arquivo que precise ler esta dentro do meu app e não fora dele.

Esse arquivo esta dentro do mesmo pacote onde esta a classe java que esta tentando ler ele, mas sempre que executo, acontece:

> exception 
>   Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Estou tentando pegar o arquivo dessa forma:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("teste.js");
```

O erro esta dando nessa linha. Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso? Como pegar o caminho do arquivo corretamente?

Obrigado.

Comment: Que eu saiba você só poderá aceder a arquivos que estejam por debaixo da pasta `\res`.

Comment: Já tentei colocar o arquivo na pasta libs e mesmo assim não funcionou. :(

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Você deve colocar na pasta Assets!

Segue um exemplo de como carregar o arquivo:

```
 /**
 * Carrega um arquivo txt 
 */
private void load(){
      try {
         final InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("dados.txt");
         final InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream); 
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader); 
            final List<String> itens = new ArrayList<String>(0);
            String line = "";
                while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null){

                    itens.add(item);
                }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```